# How to customize my account module

Tags: customer, core, customer-account

I want to override the labels of form **System -> My Account** like User Name change to Customer Name. As well as i want to remove one field Last Name from that form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy you file:

> magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Account\Edit.php

Paste at new location:

> magento\app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Account\Edit.php

The code that need to updated is this:

```
$fieldset->addField('username', 'text', array(
                'name'  => 'username',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Name'),
                'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Name'),
                'required' => true,
            )
        );
```

You can change other labels also, to whatever you want. You can always create a local to avoid over riding the core files.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Shall we override it?

Comment: Actually no, you can always create a local set up of your file in core, to avoid over riding, this magento link should be very useful for you:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_a_local_copy_of_app_code_core_mage

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I got msg on page "Topic doesnt exist yet".

Comment: Please copy paste the url, I think the underscore next to 5 is breaking the url

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for reply it works in my case. As a curiosity I want to ask that is there any other standard method to override it?

Comment: Shall we override controller by this way?